# Show individual bar count label in grouped bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I am trying to plot Male and Female in different Age Groups. I am trying to show the individual Male and Female Count in their respective bars/colours but the graphs shows the total count value in the AgeGroup. **How I am going to show/label the individual count of male and female in their respective bars/colours by AgeGroup.** Example Data is presented. Thanks

| Age | sex | AgeGroup |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | F | 18-25 Years |
| 36 | F | 36-45 Years |
| 20 | M | 18-25 Years |

Code I used:

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(demo_df, mapping = aes(x = AgeGroup)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = sex), position="dodge")+
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = scales::comma(after_stat(count))),
            nudge_y = 10000, fontface = 2) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0),
        axis.text.y.left = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y.left = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more version using `geom_col` and calculating stats before plotting:
Data from @Allan Cameron (many thanks!):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)   

demo_df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  count(sex, AgeGroup) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=AgeGroup, y=n, fill = sex))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())+
  geom_text(aes(label = n, group = sex), 
            position = position_dodge(width = .9),
            vjust = -1, size = 3)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 1, direction = - 1) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0),
        axis.text.y.left = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y.left = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to specify that the labels should be `group`ed by `sex`.
2. You also need to apply `position_dodge()` to your labels.
3. After adding the position adjustment, `nudge_y` will no longer work. You can use `vjust` instead.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(demo_df, mapping = aes(x = AgeGroup)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = sex), position="dodge")+
  geom_text(
    stat = "count", 
    aes(label = scales::comma(after_stat(count)), group = sex),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
    vjust = -1,
    fontface = 2
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0),
        axis.text.y.left = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y.left = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to add sex as a grouping variable in the text layer:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(demo_df, mapping = aes(x = AgeGroup)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = sex), position="dodge")+
  geom_text(stat = "count", 
            aes(label = scales::comma(after_stat(count)), group = sex),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), fontface = 2,
            vjust = -0.5) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0),
        axis.text.y.left = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y.left = element_blank())
```

[image]

---

**Reproducible data taken from answer to OP's previous question**

```r
demo_df <- data.frame(sex = rep(c('F', 'M'), c(514729, 470971)), 
                     AgeGroup = rep(rep(c("18-25 years", "26-35 years",
                                          "36-45 years", "46-55 years",
                                          "55-65 years", "66-75 years",
                                          "76-85 years", "86+ years"), 2),
                                    times = c(40608, 80464, 85973, 72863, 72034,
                                              62862, 54588, 45337, 37341, 77383,
                                              83620, 67367, 67190, 64193, 49171,
                                              24706)))
```